# jQuery rotate does not work in safari

Tags: jquery, safari, rotation

I had a problem with the jQuery rotate plug-in in Safari 5.x.
It seemed to work, no js errors were thrown, all the DOM elements had the styles that should have been applied after jQuery rotate work, but they were not visible (although had `visibility:visible` on them).

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to simply remove initial `visibility:visible` in CSS. It was added to hide the elements, before all animations were complete and worked fine in other browsers (even in IE, though there was another hook).

So Safar 5.x just couldn't show the elements after all transformations, render them from `visibility:hidden`.
Maybe this could help someone.